# How to prevent closing blockUI if there is input on textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, blockui

Please I need your help in this..
I have built a `$.blockUI` modal and I have an 'X' button to close it.
On button click, if there is some value on `textarea` I want to display a message that there is input and prevent closing the modal.Any ideas how can I do this?

close_modal function:

```
function close_modal(event){
      $.unblockUI();
         if (document.getElementById("comments").value.length > 0){
         alert("There is input!");

         //Here must be the code to prevent closing modal
           .
           .
           .
         //End of code

         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```js
function close_modal(event){
  if (document.getElementById("comments").value.length > 0){
      if(confirm("There is input!")) $.unblockUI();
  } else $.unblockUI();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.unblockUI()` is the function to close the modal window. If you won't run it, the modal will stay opened.

```
function canCloseTheModal() {
  return document.getElementById("comments").value.length > 0;
}

function close_modal(event){
  if (canCloseTheModal()){
    $.unblockUI();
  } else {
    // inform the user what to do
    ...
  }
}
```